# Difference between two files in terms of lines

Tags: python, windows, file, scripting

I have two huge files (file1 and file2). Both the files are organized into lines. I need to generate a third file file3 which has the lines that is there is file 1 but not in file 2. The lines are not ordered.

What is the easiest (smartest) way to get it in Windows?

Comment: why dont you just use a file diff tool like windiff http://www.grigsoft.com/download-windiff.htm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best strategy might depend on exactly how huge the files are. If the first file can fit into memory, then you can easily build a set of its lines, and removes lines from `file2` from that set. This requires the amount of memory roughly proportional to the size `file1`.

```
with open('file1') as f1:
    lineset = set(f1)
with open('file2') as f2:
    lineset.difference_update(f2)
with open('file3', 'w') as out:
    for line in lineset:
        out.write(line)
```

Note that this solution will also eliminate duplicated lines from `file1`.

Comment: With Python 2.7+ you can use the one `with` statement for all 3 context managers.

Comment: That would cause all three files to be open at the same time, which is (in this case) unneeded and therefore undesirable.

Comment: Being careful about resources is not a premature optimization. It's arguably not an optimization at all because it doesn't even affect execution time, but the amount of simultaneously acquired operating system resources. For example, on Windows, keeping a file open locks from use by other programs, so doing it for any longer than necessary creates potential problems.

Comment: It should be noted that this approach re-orders the lines in the file.

Comment: @AgDude Normally I would agree (and consider an order-preserving solution), but this question does state that "The lines are not ordered."

Answer (score 0):

While I'd probably use the set approach myself, another option is `difflib` in the standard library:

```
from difflib import Differ

with open('a.txt') as a, open('b.txt') as b:
    missing_from_b = [
        diff[2:] for diff in Differ().compare(a.readlines(), b.readlines())
        if diff.startswith('-')
    ]
    print missing_from_b
```